# Why mac is required in React Native Ios

Tags: ios, react-native

I understood that when you code in React, it allows you to use your code both for Android and for iOS.
However, when I go to the main site it says that I need a Mac in order to code iOS applications.

Can someone explain the meaning of this, please?

Comment: Apple only lets you develop for iOS on a Mac.

Comment: So how does React work? I thought you can cross-platform...

Comment: It is cross-platform, but you still need to compile native components.

Answer (score 1):

You need a mac, with xcode to build your app and test it on iOS devices.

The code is shared and compatible as long as you use the react native components.

Comment: Yes but Xcode uses Swift or Objective-C, isn't React programmed in other compiler?

Comment: React = JavaScript, ReactNative = Bridge between native (Java, Objective-C, Swift) and JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot can you please explain what makes a language Native?

Comment: In this case native is Java for android and Objective-C / Swift is for iOS. Additionally, Javascript is a Scripting language not a general purpose programming language like the others.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a clear idea.

[image]